# Can a sqlite batch be reused in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

So if I have an sql batch can it be reused again and again? So for example,

```
await _db.transaction((txn) async {
  final batch = txn.batch();

  // Some queries that adds query to batch.
  
  await batch.commit();

  // Some queries that adds query to next set of batch.
  
  await batch.commit();

  // Some queries that adds query to next set of batch.
  
  await batch.commit();
});
```

So is it okay to use one batch and perform multiple set of queries?

Comment: What’s the use case behind this?

Comment: I need one set of batch to check if multiple items exists and next set of batch to insert into database.

Answer (score 0):

From sqflite author,

> No a batch can only be committed once. You have to create a new batch.